# Pass mysql.h path to gcc compiler

Tags: mysql, c, database, windows, gcc

I've created a database using mysql, and now i need to connect it with C, basically just to call some functions, already created in SQL.

I've installed the "C Connector" from mysql website. When i try to compile my program using 
`gcc db.c` i have this error:

> db.c:2:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

So, looking on the forum I understood that i need to include 'mysql.h' path when i compile my program, using -I, but it stills gives me an error.

The path where is mysql.h is the following:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
gcc db.c -l mysql
```

That is usually how you compile programs with libraries such as this. if that does not work, try following this link: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-building-clients.html

Comment: This gives me the same error >db.c:2:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.